# Is there a chart that shows the daily Eth mined vs the amount of Eth burned in the day?

Tags: mining, block-reward

I'm curious to find a chart that shows the amount of Eth emitted in a day vs the amount of Eth burned in a day. And show the exact total of Eth being released per day.

Answer (score 0):

https://watchtheburn.com/

The charts are lacking, but the data you're looking for is there.

Answer (score 0):

http://ultrasound.money/ is another site that has that data. It also has a leaderboard of the contracts burning the most money.